# Injecting an alias into a “.bash_profile” file without overwriting it in macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I recently installed [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) via Homebrew and while attempting to utilize it in terminal I recieved the following message

> Seems like fuck alias isn't configured! Please put eval $(thefuck --alias) in your ~/.bashrc. More details - https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck#manual-installation.

Reminding me that I hadn’t completely finished the install and still needed to input `eval $(thefuck --alias)` into my `.bash_profile` to get it to work properly.

I’m fairly sure the command for inserting this would be something like `echo "eval $(thefuck --alias)" >> ~/.bash_profile` is this correct? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m fairly sure the command for inserting this would be something like `echo "eval $(thefuck --alias)" >> ~/.bash_profile` is this correct? Any help would be much appreciated!

All this command does is append text (via `echo` and `>>`) into the target file—which in this case is `~/.bash_profile`. So yes, the command is correct.

Or you could just follow the instructions on the [manual installation](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck#manual-installation) page you show in the error message which clearly states:

> You should place this command in your .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc or other startup script:
>
> ```
> eval $(thefuck --alias)
> ```

Meaning, this isn’t magic: Just open up your `.bash_profile` file using whatever editor you prefer to use—such as Nano—and just add the line `eval "$(thefuck --alias)"` to that file.

Then either close and reopen your terminal—or just type `source ~/.bash_profile`—and you should be good to go.

Comment: The command is not quite correct. `$( )` will be evaluated inside double-quotes, so `echo "eval $(thefuck --alias)" >> ~/.bash_profile` will run the command `thefuck --alias` and put `eval WhatEverThatOutput` in the .bash_profile. You could do it with single-quotes instead of double-quotes, but if you already did the double-quote version, you'll need to edit your .bash_profile file to fix it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the correction Gordon, I completely missed that!